# reading and writing from registers with swapped memory aadress

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to find the solution to following bug:

Suppose there are two registers A & B with memory addresses Addr1 & Addr2 respectively. Whenever we are trying to read/write from register A it doesn't read/write from respective address(Addr1) of A instead it performs read/write operation from address(Addr2) of B. Same is true whenever we try to read or write from register B, it performs read/write operation from address of A i.e. addresses are swapped for read/write operation. 
We dont have access to any other thing except these two addresses.

What kind of logic or pattern will be able to find out the above bug ?

Please give some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Uh? Is this a REAL bug, or something made up by whoever is training you? And what have you yourself tried to solve the problem? (It is much easier to explain where someone is going wrong from what they have tried than to explain the entire solution).

Comment: Perhaps if you post your code, we might be able to help...?

Comment: Do you want to do it in `c/c++` or `Verilog`?

Comment: I would suggest a logic analyser to find out what's wrong with the address-decoding hardware.

Comment: Martin James: You are right...this seems to be a hardware issue with address decoder.

Comment: Qiu: I would like to do it in verilog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase the question my understanding of the problem is:

1. Trying to read and write to location A actually perform operation on location B.
2. Trying to perform an operation on B actually performs it on A.

Solution:

The data sheet or specification have the address locations the wrong way around.

From the outside if I write to a location and try to read from the same location and get the data I wrote not sure how that is a bug. Internally there may be an issue if some thing else is inconsistent or you are not using a power of 2 memory and a different set of locations do not exist compared to the datasheet.